# How can I make script globally executable in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, python

I have a bash script which I would to like to execute from everywhere (like other Linux basic commands, for example `ls`). I tried to follow this [tutorial](http://oxaric.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/make-a-bash-script-globally-executabl/) but it doesn't work, I always get `command not found`.

Also would be nice if there is a way how to execute directly Python script in this way, currently I have .py file with the script and then file .sh which calls `python /path/to/it`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write a python script that you can execute it in at least the following three ways:

1 Start python with the script as an argument.

Example: `/usr/local/bin/python-2.5 myscript.py`

2 Start the script with shebang interpreter.

This means that the very first line starts with #! (also called a shebang) followed by a space (or most often not!) and the full path to the interpreter.

Example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python-2.5
#
# My test script!
#
Do something
```

Notice that I added comments **after** the first line. Do not add them above it since then the first line no longer starts with a shebang.

3 Start the script with `#!/usr/bin/env python`

This is more or less the same as option 2, except that env will find python for you. If python ever moves to a different location or a new version then you do not have to update all your scripts.

This is the preferred solution

---

So much for the part where you used a sh script to call python /path/to/it.  You now now how to skip that part.

The second part of your question seems that your script is not found. To find a script or program you either need to specify the full path to it (e.g. /usr/local/bin/myscript.py` or it needs to be in your path.

You can check what your current path is set to with `echo $PATH`.

It probably includes /usr/local/bin/, which means that any program or script dropped in the directory /usr/local/bin/ will be found.  If it does not add that path to the system wide default.  (Note: start a login shell to test this after changing this. Changing the config file without starting a new shell will not reflect the changes).

Lastly I skipped the part where you want the script to be executable. You already had that in the tutorial you linked you.